# Scala's sealed class "scope of seal"

Tags: scala

I know that Scala allows to derive from sealed class if it is placed in the same file. May be there is a special construction or, if not, it makes sense to allow something like this:

```
sealed[Derived/*, list of allowed to derive*/] class Base
class Derived extends Base
```

This syntax will be like "Scope of protection":

```
class A{
  private[A] val value = 10
}
```

So it will allow to place Derived class to separate file.

Comment: Are you trying to find a way to put `case class` in a separate file?

Comment: In the most cases - yes? But also for classes which are not `case`.

Comment: Keep in mind that `sealed` is not transitive across subclasses. I.e., `sealed` applies only to *direct* subclasses of the class marked `sealed`. If any of those subclasses (or traits) are not `final`, those subclasses are not themselves sealed and may be further subclassed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sealed class cannot have any new subclasses added except the ones in the same file.

**Reasons for the design**

1 - The programmers only need to worry about the subclasses they already know about.

2 - You get better compiler support because the compiler will flag missing combinations of pattern with a warning message.

Comment: May be it makes sense to allow only classes which are in the same package?

Comment: @serg.f you could play around with the Java technique of package-protected constructors.

Comment: It's pretty hard to junit test stuff unless you create testing classes in that file

Comment: This doesn't really work when you need to have 15 different versions of your `sealed trait`.  Having a `sealed[packageName]` option would really help solve this